# Android - How to align an image center relative to the textview

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have an text view as show above and an info icon next to the text view. All is fine here but I wish to have the info icon aligned center to the textview. As of now it is aligned top right relative to the text view. I wish it to be aligned center right relative to the text view

The XML Layout file is below

```
        <RelativeLayout
             android:orientation="horizontal" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            > 

        <TextView               
            android:id="@+id/ViewMessageOne"                
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="sans" 
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            />   

         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/banner_portrait"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ViewMessageOne"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:gravity="center"               
           />


         </RelativeLayout>
```

Please point me in the right direction. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Try:**

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
```

**EDIT:**

You could also just change the height to match the `TextView`, as your `ImageView` gravity is set to `center`.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ViewMessageOne"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/banner_portrait" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Unless you have a specific need for the `ImageView`, you could take that out and use [drawableRigh](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableRight) on your `TextView`

```
<TextView               
        android:id="@+id/ViewMessageOne"                
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/banner_portrait"   // here
        />
```

Comment: @codeMagic..how to align an image at the center of textview..           `android:drawableRight="@drawable/abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha ` This aligns at right but I want it at center

Comment: @PrathibhaKirthi I don't see anything for that [Here in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) you may need to set up a layout with a TextView and an ImageVIew to get it in the center

Comment: @codeMagic What I've done is aligned it to right then I've given left and right padding..It came to centre..Now I need a button which has 1 side Oval shape and other side flat.

Comment: @PrathibhaKirthi I don't know without searching besides creating your own shape image in an editor and using that. But this is really another question in itself.